# Get all rows data from a table using Cursor in C program

Tags: sql, c, database, oracle

I am using below code in my C program which is connecting to oracle database and getting values from database:

```
EXEC SQL DECLARE testCursor CURSOR FOR
 SELECT DISTINCT
    pval1,
    pval2,   
  FROM t_table;
```

and then in main function below code:

```
EXEC SQL
          FETCH testCursor
          INTO
              :w_val1,
              :w_val2
```

I am getting the value in w_val1 and w_val2 ,but i am just getting a single row data . How to loop it to get all row data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to code a loop in C.

For example:

```
EXEC SQL WHENEVER NOT FOUND DO break:
for (;;) 
{ 
    EXEC SQL FETCH testCursor INTO :w_val1, :w_val2; 
    ... 
}
```

See
[19C embedded cursors](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpcc/embedded-SQL.html#GUID-7FF86597-BB63-40C2-BFE4-09C618672EBA) for details.